# Why isn't this define variable sticking in PHP?

Tags: php

Can someone explain to me why in the world my `DB_PREFIX` variable is not accessible? When echoed, it just prints out `DB_PREFIX` to screen. All of my other defined variables are being printed to screen just fine, when called of course.

Help?

debug.php

```
require_once('db/config.php');

$conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $conn);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `' . DB_PREFIX . 'test01`';

echo DB_PREFIX;
?>
```

db/config.php:

```
<?php
/* MySQL Settings */
/** MySQL Database Name */
define('DB_NAME', 'urdasandbox');

/** MySQL Username */
define('DB_USER', 'urdasandbox');

/** MySQL Password */
define('DB_PASS', 'wouldnt you like to know kid-o');

/** MySQL Hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'yourmother.trebek.com');

/** Database Charset */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** Database Table Type */
define('DB_TABLETYPE', 'InnoDB');

/** Database Collate Type */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**
 * DB Table prefix.
 */
define('DB_PREFIX', 'udb_');

/** absolute path to the directory. */
if(!defined('ABSPATH'))
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
?>
```

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(-1);` and see if it throws an error

Comment: Turn on error reporting to see if it's complaining about something. If a constant isn't defined it assumes a string with the name as its value.

Comment: what is the result of: if (defined('DB_PREFIX')) ?

Comment: Adding `error_reporting(-1);` said that it was a undefined constant. However after re-uploading my files, after I had rm -rf the sandbox directory, the echo is now printing correctly. It might have been cached or something :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the directory, and re-uploading my file set corrected the issue. Either it was a cache or apache thing... But it is fixed now with zero code change.